# Adding a view causes my collection view to go back to original frame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my collection view, when a user clicks a cell, i want my collection view to move down to the bottom of the screen, and then i want a short UIView to appear above it.

This is what I have tried

```
lazy var watchControlView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return view
}()


func showWatchView(selectedPath: Int) {
    // This function is called inside of the didSelectItemAt: method
    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            let newClipCollectionHeight = self.clipsCollectionView.frame.height * 0.9
            self.clipsCollectionView.frame = CGRect(x: self.clipsCollectionView.frame.origin.x, y: keyWindow.frame.height - newClipCollectionHeight, width: self.clipsCollectionView.frame.width, height: newClipCollectionHeight)
            let height = keyWindow.frame.height - self.clipsCollectionView.frame.height - self.toolBar.frame.height
            self.watchControlView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.toolBar.frame.height, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)
            self.view.addSubview(self.watchControlView)
        })
        clipsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The first thing i did was try to move the collection view down when a user clicked a cell. The code above for that worked. However, when i add the subview, the collection view moves back to its original position, and the view lays on top of the collection view.

Anyone have a fix to this problem?

Comment: If you are using auto layout then you need to manipulate the constraints not the frame

Comment: I am using auto layout. My collection view is horizontally and vertically in the container and has a bottomLayoutGuide.Top constant set to 148. So how can i manipulate the constraints to shift it to the bottom?

Comment: 1. Previously add the view where it should be and add a height constraint with 0.
2. Also add a vertical spacing constraint to collection view
3. When you need to show view just set the height constraint to it and adjust collection view height and position using constraint and it will be the best approach to manage views

Comment: ####You have no relation between view and collection. Both are child view but what will be position to whom respect you have to specified then it will be perfectly okay

Comment: Expose the collection view's top constraint, and manipulate the constraint's constant value to achieve what you want

Comment: In the Interface Builder, find the top constraint of the UICollectionView that you set. CTRL+Drag to your source code to expose the constraint.

Comment: Work with constraints. Please use collectionview's hight constraint by making its outlet in controller class.